# How can I configure my target to use a specific Info.plist in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, target

I have an Xcode project with many, many targets (iPhone, iPad, OS X).

I need to have different Info.plist files for each of my targets.

For iOS, I don't run into any issue, everything builds fine. But for OS X, I get the following message:

```
No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file, exiting
```

In the OS X target build settings I've entered:

```
Info.plist File: /MyApp/Resources/Info-osx.plist
```

How can I get around this issue? Is there something I did forgot to specify?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Have you set NSPrincipalClass in the info.plist for the OS X target?
>   The NSPrincipalClass is the main class used to start the OS X app.

by rckoenes in the last comment

This was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The path the info.plist in the build settings is relative in you project source.
  If you remove the first `/` it should work.

Also don't include the `info.plist` in the target, when you compile your project it is generated in the app for you.

Comment: The path I gave was an example, in reality it is defined with ($SRC_ROOT). But I tried your suggestion, which leads to the same issue. Also my Info.plist in not part of the target. So same point so far.

Comment: Have you set [`NSPrincipalClass`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW11) in the `info.plist` for the OS X target?  The `NSPrincipalClass` is the main class used to start the OS X app.

Comment: Awesome, your last comment help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, but the solution to solve my problem was [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/5e9jgd/no_infoplist_file_in_application_bundle_or_no/), by setting `Create Info.plist Section in Binary` to `Yes` inside `Build Settings`.

Hope it helps others in future.